# WordPress Plugin to display a list of input fields which are visible to everyone

Tags: wordpress, wiki

I am sorry if the title was not descriptive enough, this is the best I could think of. Any edit suggestion is welcome.

I want to display a list of editable text fields, which are updated by any visitor, and all updates are live and public to everyone else. The submitted fields may or may not be editable anymore.

So, once a visitor visits the page, there will be a list of empty blanks/fields, short text fields for instance. They will fill in their name and their details, then submit. All other visitors will see that this field is taken/filled.

The reason is that there will be a list of offerings, and the link will be distributed among participants only, each participant can fill a "slot" with their details after seeing which slots are available.

Edit: Think of a survey/form, but submissions remain visible to everyone. Anyone can edit any of the fields, and they remain public whether or not they have data/response.

I don't need any extra validation or complexity. Logging in is not required.

- Preferably a WordPress Plugin, standalone web apps are accepted, too
- Preferably free, reasonably paid solutions are accepted, too.

Comment: Like a commenting system? Wordpress has that built-in. If that's not it, I don't get it. Can you draw a sketch maybe?

Comment: I don't think that the default commenting system will work. For each blank/field, there will be a title/label. Think of a form, but each field/question can be filled by one visitor only.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution that (could) work for me was editable table.

I found 2 candidates plugins:

- Ninja Tables
- wpDataTables

Embedding Google spreadsheet that allows everyone to edit may work, too

Comment: This is not really an answer.  You could make it one by posting which one you ended up using and why.